# MySQL JOIN a table or another

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo, search-engine

**Context:**
The database is about phones. I have a *search engine* in a `TABLE sav` (records of "after sales service") which has a field `phone` containing the **IMEI** (its unique id) of the phone.
In some case, the phone is going back in our stock (deleted from the `TABLE sales` and inserted into the `TABLE stock`) and an other phone is returned to the customer.

**Issue:**
In the search engine of the "after sales service", I use to `LEFT JOIN sales`, but in case a phone has gone back in `stock`, it won't be found by its **IMEI**.
**To sum:**

> I need to join a table if a record is found, else, join an other table.

**My actual query:**
I shortened it (`[...]`) to make it readable:

```
SELECT sav.id, sav.phone, [...] FROM sav 
LEFT JOIN sales ON (sav.phone = sales.imei)
LEFT JOIN stock_model ON (sales.model = stock_model.id) [...]
WHERE (sales.imei LIKE :search_1 OR [...])
OR (sales.imei LIKE :search_2 OR [...])
OR [...]
```

I need to change the 2nd line but I don't understand how. The questions I read before seem to answer specific cases.

**EDIT: table structure & dummy data**
I won't post irrelevant fields (too many)
**`TABLE`** `sav`

```
| id | phone     | issue   | replacement_imei | ...
----------------------------------------------------
| 35 | 123456789 | battery | NULL             | ...     <-- phone n°1
| 54 | 987654321 | screen  | 147258369        | ...     <-- phone n°2 replaced by phone n°3
```

**`TABLE`** `stock`

```
| id  | imei      | model | color | memory | ...
-------------------------------------------------
| 68  | 369258147 | 2     | 4     | 1      | ...
| 92  | 987654321 | 5     | 8     | 3      | ...     <-- phone n°2 replaced by phone n°3
```

**`TABLE`** `sales`

```
| id  | imei      | model | color | memory | ...
-------------------------------------------------
| 68  | 123456789 | 2     | 4     | 1      | ...     <-- phone n°1
| 103 | 147258369 | 5     | 8     | 3      | ...     <-- phone n°3 replaced phone n°2
```

**EDIT: complete search engine [PHP]**:
In case the whole function helps:

```
$keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
$query = "SELECT sav.id, sav.phone, sav.date, sav.nom, sav.issue, sav.replacement_imei, sav.commentaire, sav.attente, sav.pieces, sav.frais, sav.date_envoi, sav.tracking, sav.termine FROM sav LEFT JOIN sales ON (sav.phone = sales.imei) LEFT JOIN stock_memory ON (sales.memory = stock_memory.id) LEFT JOIN stock_color ON (sales.color = stock_color.id) LEFT JOIN stock_model ON (sales.model = stock_model.id) LEFT JOIN stock_grade ON (sales.grade = stock_grade.id) WHERE ";

// Makes a long query returning each row where at least 1 keyword matches 1 column
$query_array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($keywords); $i += 1) {
        $query .= " ( sales.imei LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR ( sales.snowden = 1 AND 'snowden'= :search_" . $i . " )";
        $query .= " OR stock_model.name LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR stock_color.name LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR stock_memory.amount LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR stock_grade.name LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.id LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR DATE_FORMAT(sav.date, '%d/%m/%Y') LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.nom LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.issue LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.replacement_imei LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.commentaire LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.attente LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.pieces LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.frais LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR DATE_FORMAT(sav.date_envoi, '%d/%m/%Y') LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR sav.tracking LIKE :search_" . $i;
        $query .= " OR ( sav.termine = 1 AND 'termine'= :search_" . $i . " )";
        // $query .= "LIKE :search_" . $i;
        if ($i != (count($keywords) - 1)) {
            $query .= " ) AND ";
        } else {
            $query .= " ) ";
        }
        if (strtolower($keywords[$i]) == 'snowden' || strtolower($keywords[$i]) == 'termine') {
            $query_array['search_' . $i] = $keywords[$i];
        } else {
            $query_array['search_' . $i] = "%" . $keywords[$i] . "%";
        }
    }
    $query .= "ORDER BY sav.id DESC LIMIT $offset, $limit";
    $results = $this->bdd->prepare($query);
    $results->execute($query_array);
    return $results;
```

Comment: Please share the table structures and some dummy data reflecting the real data post these as ascii data tables not images., Also post the expected outout as a ascii data table.

Comment: Hi @RaymondNijland, I edited my post with the relevant fields. You can see `sav.phone` matches with `stock.imei`/`sales.imei`

Answer (score 0):

First I get all data with full outer join, then Sales.Model => Select all ID from Stock_Model.

```
SELECT sav.id, sav.phone, [...] FROM sav 
FULL OUTER JOIN sales ON (sav.phone = sales.imei)
WHERE sav.phone = sales.imei or sales.model in (select Id from stock_model)
```

Comment: Hello !
You can't get the `stock_model.id` if you haven't the phone. There is no `sav.model` field

Comment: @AymDev I edited my answer can you check this one.

Comment: The issue I struggle with isn't about the `stock_model` table. I want to join `sav.phone` on `sales.imei` OR `stock.imei`. The `WHERE` clause has to be as I placed it, there's only `JOIN`s before it. After it are the multiple conditions of the search engine.

Comment: I don't mind where clause because you can add any expression after. I want to help you for joins.